# Connect Modbus Device from Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have researched on how to connect modbus devices from iOS and got many useful answers such as [Modbus from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652140/how-do-you-communicate-to-a-modbus-device-within-an-iphone-application). Is there any SDK available to connect to Modbus devices using Xamarin as their ios Counterparts? for e.g. [this](https://github.com/LarsJK/ObjectiveLibModbus) and [this](https://github.com/ktsakaguchi/SwiftLibModbus).

To Explain further,

1. Let's assume there is a Modbus compatible device. For e.g. WAGO Remote IO
2. If we need to communicate to it from C# Desktop application, there are lots of tutorials available. For e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP8BUNTQ0HQ)
3. If we need to connect from iOS app developed in ObjC, we can use [this](https://github.com/LarsJK/ObjectiveLibModbus).
4. If we need to connect from iOS app developed in swift, we can use [this](https://github.com/ktsakaguchi/SwiftLibModbus).
5. I am trying to connect from iOS app developed in Xamarin.iOS, using NModbus C#, but having no luck.

So, question is, is there any C# counterparts available for Swift and ObjectiveC libraries of Modbus ?

Comment: You may have to do a binding of the Obj-C Modbus SDK. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/